# Toogleble menu left slide appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a toggle window to pop coming from the right to the left.

I have tried this:

```
$('#menuDiv').show({ direction: "left", easing:"linear" }, 1750 );
```

But this has 2 problem:

1. The time 1750 is not having any effect.
2. The windows pops top to down with half width and right to left at the same time. (In a diagonal way).

Any help appreciated.

I'm using the [jQuery UI library](https://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. You didn't specify the type of effect you want, which is the required option `effect`
2. You tried to specify the duration as second parameter, while you should have used the option `duration`

A working version of your code:

```
$('#menuDiv').show({
  effect: "slide",
  direction: "left",
  easing:"linear",
  duration: 1750 
});
```

Comment: It's slide, I put it on the title but forgot to put into the body. I will test it tomorrow already left work today. Any way thanks I will let you know if it worked :)

Comment: It worked very well, only had to change the direction to right. What's the diference beetween "drop"  and "slide", I tried both and noticed no diference.

Comment: I think for `show`, it doesn't make a difference, but you are corrept, `slide` is more suitable, I've edited my answer